# What is the equivalent of a for-each loop in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

I recently started working with jQuery and was wondering how I would iterate through a collection (an array or list of items) of items and sum their contents.

Does jQuery have something like a for-loop like many other languages do?

Would there be an easy way to implement this - if this isn't easily do-able?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you are looking for is the jQuery [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function - which will allow you to iterate through any given field(s) and perform an action.

**Usage:**

```
var array = ["stack", "overflow"];
$.each(array, function() {
      // Perform actions here (this) will be your current item
});
```

**Example (Summing an Array of Integers):**

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var sum = 0;

$.each(array, function() {
  sum += (this);
});
alert(sum);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5):

`$.each(function)` and `$(...).each(function)` both accurately perform the equivalent of a for-each loop, but the actual JavaScript for-each equivalent is the `for(... in ...)` loop.

```
for (variable in object)
{
    // code to be executed
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for_in.asp

This isn't jQuery-specific, but hey, jQuery is just a JavaScript library after all. :)

Comment: And this spares memory which can be useful on mobile devices. Why doesn't Apple the simply make an IPHONE WITH 4 GB RAM! D:<

Answer (score 4):

For an array, see Rionmonster's answer. For all items matchins a selector:

```
$("a").each(function() {
   alert($(this).attr('href'));
});
```